# What is the correct way to update state that is teleported with Context after a fetch with useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I've created a demo example to help explain the question. Below I use the `useFetch` hook from [usehooks](https://usehooks.com/usefetch).

Given the Pokemon API I'd only like to store some of the data received from the fetch request. I would like to pass that data along to sub-components.

What is the correct way to update setAbilities and setName? Any other more beneficial ways to do this than using `React.useState` and `React.useEffect`?

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useFetch } from "@uidotdev/usehooks";

const PokemonContext = React.createContext()

export function Demo() {
    const { error, data } = useFetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");
    const [abilities, setAbilities] = React.useState(null)
    const [name, setName] = React.useState(null)
    

    // ... update with setAbilities and setName

    if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;
    if (!data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return (
        <PokemonContext.Provider value={{abilities, name}}>
            <Pokemon />
        </PokemonContext.Provider>
    );
}

function Pokemon () {
    const {abilities, name} = React.useContext(PokemonContext)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <div>
                Abilities:
                <ul>
                    {abilities.map((ability, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>{ability.ability.name}</li>
                     ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've tried using React.useEffect and then use the setAbilities and setName but I don't know whether that is the correct way of handling this in React.

Edit:

This is how I would go about solving it. Is this optimal?

```
import * as React from "react"
import {useFetch} from "../hooks/useFetch.jsx";

const PokemonContext = React.createContext()

export function Hooks() {
    const { error, data } = useFetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");
    const [abilities, setAbilities] = React.useState([])
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("")

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setAbilities(data.abilities)
            setName(data.name)
        }
    }, [data])

    if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;
    if (!data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return (
        <PokemonContext.Provider value={{abilities, name}}>
            <Pokemon />
        </PokemonContext.Provider>
    );
}

function Pokemon () {
    const {abilities, name} = React.useContext(PokemonContext)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <div>
                Abilities:
                <ul>
                    {abilities.map((ability, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>{ability.ability.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Putting it inside a useEffect would be the way to go (assuming it's used correctly) - mainly because it can guarantee that the API request is only sent once

Comment: Thanks, @BenGooding! I updated the question with an edit on how I would (and have) solved it for more context. Wondering if there are any optimal way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not render the abilities directly but render a function which takes the abilities as a parameter, alter them as needed and return the altered values:

```
formattedAbilities = (abilities) => {
    let formattedAbilities = abilities;
    //do whatever you want to the formattedAbilities
    return formattedAbilities;
}

function Pokemon () {
    const {abilities, name} = React.useContext(PokemonContext)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <div>
                Abilities:
                <ul>
                    {abilities ? formattedAbilities(abilities).map((ability, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>{ability.ability.name}</li>
                    )) : null}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```